Scratch: Broadcast message spawning more and more clones each time, how to fix
For some strange reason, clones duplicate other clones but does not do anything to add to a variable.
Click this to get the image, i cant embedd images yet. But I believe that this clone script creates another clone. Here is the code to summon a clone: I still dont understand why it happens but it does not add anything to the variables, no matter what approach I do, only with clones.
After all clones on screen are hidden, they only get deleted then.
I have also tried to make a clone with a personal value so that it could only create clones through the broadcast, but after 1 clone created it stops working so i believe that is not the way to go.
here is the link: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/1004562917/

Can you share a screenshot of the code in the question itself? Links can disappear over time. Please be specific about what you tried, exactly, and explain exactly what the application is and what you're trying to achieve, because there may be a fundamentally different approach that works better than your attempted solution. Thanks.

i have scr3eenshotted!

I am unsure if this is your problem, but when you use the broadcast message block, it runs it on the clones as well because the broadcast goes to all sprites.
You could use a sprite only variable to keep an id for each clone. Then you could make the original have a different id and check for that id on the receive message script.
define clone:
set ID to clone
create a clone of myself
set ID to original

when I receive message clone:
if ID = original
clone


If you're talking about how when you try to create a clone on one sprite, but it ends up happening on clones too, meaning it reaches the 300 clone limit too fast, then you can try moving the "Create Clone Of Myself" Block to another sprite that isn't the sprite you're cloning. Also, after you move the block, be sure to set the "Create Clone Of Myself" Block to "Create Clone Of [sprite you want to clone]".
